# How can I program a "for loop" where a php value sets a html element value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, for-loop

How could I do `if value ==` in a for loop, so that I dont need to do the value == check 10 times?

```
function getComboA(selectObject) {
    var value = selectObject.value;
    if (value == 1) {
        document.getElementById("selected_slot").value = <?php echo $selected_slot1 ?>;
        document.getElementById("selected_value").value = <?php echo $selected_value1 ?>;
    } else if (value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("selected_slot").value = <?php echo $selected_slot2 ?>;
        document.getElementById("selected_value").value = <?php echo $selected_value2 ?>;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  But from what you had given, I think you asking for a flag case.  Set $isflag as true if if value ==. And in loop check, if flag has been set or not.  Loop only if flag not set.

Comment: I have a html dropdown, where a user can select an Item from 1 - 10. If an item from the dropdown is selected, javascript sets values to some html elements with "document.getElementById("selected_slot").value = <?php echo $selected_slot4 ?>;"

The ID for all slots 1 - 10 is the same, but the value wich is set, comes from a database as a php variable. The variable in php is the ID from html plus the slot number at the end. ID: selected_slot, and the php variable: selected_slot4

There are 10 slots, so my code has 10 if checks. Is it possible to loop the javascript value in a for loop?

Comment: @ThomasGlauser my answer allows you to avoid multiple repetition of code by using an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make array and send it to js.

```
<?
$arr = [
  [ 'slot'=> $selected_slot1, 'value'=>  $selected_value1 ],
  [ 'slot'=> $selected_slot2, 'value'=>  $selected_value2 ],
];   
?> 
function getComboA(selectObject) {
     ar = <? echo json_encode($arr) ?>;
     var value = selectObject.value;
     document.getElementById("selected_slot").value = ar[value-1].slot;
     document.getElementById("selected_value").value = ar[value-1].value
}
```